# Issues with arrays and repeating outputs

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem that deals with reading a file and putting them into an array.
Then subtracting the arrays to equal 0

Here is what I got so far:

```
        Scanner infile2 = new Scanner(new File(fname));
        int [] nums = new int [n];
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            {
            nums[i] = infile2.nextInt();
            }
                for (int j = 0; j<n-1;j++){
                    for (int k = j+1; k<n;k++){
                        if (nums[j]+nums[k]==0){
                            int val = nums[j]+nums[k];

                        }
                    }
                }
                    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing it this way

```
Scanner infile2 = new Scanner(new File(fname));
int [] nums = new int [n];
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    nums[i] = infile2.nextInt();
}

for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
    for (int k = j+1; k<n;k++){
        if (nums[j]+nums[k]==0){
            int val = nums[j]+nums[k];
            System.out.println("num["+j+"]"+ " + " +"num["+k+"]"+" = " + nums[j] + " + " + nums[k] + " = " + val);
         }
    }
}
```

take the nested loop out, then it should solve the repeated count issue

Here is what i tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        String fname = "PathToFile/a.txt";
        int n = 0;
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File(fname));
        while (infile.hasNextInt()){
        n++;
        infile.nextInt();
        }
        Scanner infile2 = new Scanner(new File(fname));
        int [] nums = new int [n];
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = infile2.nextInt();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j<n-1;j++){
            for (int k = j+1; k<n;k++){
                if (nums[j]+nums[k]==0){
                    int val = nums[j]+nums[k];
                    System.out.println("num["+j+"]"+ " + " +"num["+k+"]"+" = " + nums[j] + " + " + nums[k] + " = " + val);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

result i am getting

```
num[1] + num[4] = -40 + 40 = 0
num[1] + num[7] = -40 + 40 = 0
num[3] + num[6] = -10 + 10 = 0
```

Comment: I was just going to say this. It's too much unnecessary complexity; it also might be worth adding an integer to the text file to specify the size of the list to avoid reading it twice. Otherwise, I'd just use an arraylist.

Comment: I took out the nested loop but now the output becomes
`num[6] + num[10] = 0 + 0 = 0
num[6] + num[11] = 0 + 0 = 0
num[10] + num[11] = 0 + 0 = 0`

the problem is I do not know how to use an arraylist since we only learned so much

Comment: @user3395013 Note that there is some small difference from my loops and yours, the loop condition part where j < n and k < n

Comment: @Luuk :) the dot add method is indeed nice

Comment: The only problem I'm getting is that I cant get the taregetted values

Comment: You might want to show us more code (or your revised code). The sample list you provided only had 9 numbers, if you're getting num[10] and num[11] elements, something is going wrong with reading in the values. For some reason the elements you listed in the comment are set to 0 which also should not happen.

Comment: I tried, and i did get your expected output, (1,4), (1,7) and (3,6)

Comment: is it just my Eclipse program then? because I keep getting the same values as I posted :(

Comment: @user3395013 i didn't copy the whole program, but i tried the one i posted, check out the edited version of the solution

Comment: @user3395013 n has value of 9, it doesn't make sense to get num[10] and num[11], j and k wont go up to 10 and 11